# ggplot and ggsave() font incompatibility after upgrading to Mac Sonoma

Tags: r, ggplot2, macos-sonoma, ggsave

I upgraded my Mac OS recently to Sonoma, and since then I've run into a very strange error when I'm trying to use certain fonts in ggplot --> ggsave in R...

For example, when using the font Lexend Deca, my plots work just fine when I print them out in my environment. Everything looks as it should and as it has always looked.

But when I try to save them to any folder using ggsave(), all of the text in the plot disappears in the files that are saved.

This exact code worked just fine, ggsave and all, a few weeks ago. The only thing I can think of that changed is my OS. Does anyone have any experience with this, or any recommendations of how to debug?